# create a listbox and show the selected options in jquery

Tags: jquery

I have created a Listbox and selected 3 options. What should I add to this code so the browser shows the selected options correctly?

HTML code:

```
 <select name="s1" multiple>
    <option value="India">India</option>
    <option value="America">America</option>
    <option value="Africa">Africa</option>
    <option value="Japan">Japan</option>
    <option value="Kenya">Kenya</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('select[name^="s1"] option[value="India"]').attr("selected", "selected");
    $('select[name^="s1"] option[value="Japan"]').attr("selected", "selected");
    $('select[name^="s1"] option[value="Kenya"]').attr("selected", "selected");
});

</script>
```

can anyone tell this to me.. Thanks in advance.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8yfvycuk/) with to code above

Comment: It is working for me: http://jsfiddle.net/1qejcco2/ ? (FF and Chrome)

Comment: Its working on IE too. (I'm sorry I have sinned)

Comment: What does not work for you or what exactly do you want to achieve ?

Comment: if i select anyone option means, i get a result like following: You selected:selected options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally i got my result,by include the following code into that, whenever i click the options it displays the selected options..

```
 <script>   
    $("select").change(function () {
   var str = ""+"You Selected: ";
   $("select option:selected").each(function () {
       str += $(this).text() + " ";
   });
   $("div").text(str);
   }) .trigger("change");  
  });</script>
```

The code works well in Chrome,Firefox and IE.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems working fine as you posted. but you can do it with less code like:

```
$('select[name^="s1"]').val(['India', 'Japan', 'Kenya']);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/1qejcco2/)